# Bash : "done" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: linux, bash, dash-shell

I get the following error when i try to run the script

```
Bash : "done" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

I tried both bash and dash ,i get the same error.

```
topip4="false"
topip6="false"
topurl="false"
for par in "$@" ; do
    if [ "$par" == "-topip4" ] ; then
        topip4="true"
    else if [ "$par" == "-topip6" ] ; then
        topip6="true"
    else if [ "$par" == "-topurl" ] ; then
        topurl="true"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You might actually be better off using [case](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) for the given example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `else if` into `elif`.

Comment: oh i am always forgetting it!!damn you java